# How to upgrade ssh version from 8.2 to 8.6 in ubuntu machine

Tags: upgrade, ssh, openssh, vulnerability

I have tried to install ssh version 8.6 with ref link https://blog.jonkimi.com/2020/04/17/Upgrade-openssh-server-on-Ubuntu/. After installation when I run command "ssh -V" it shows latest version (8.6) but when I telnet it displays older version (8.2) of ssh. for Vulnerability Scan I am trying to install latest version of ssh in my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS system.

Comment: You've provided no OS & release, and haven't indicated if you're talking about the server or client... If you're worried about a CVE, then providing that CVE that worries you may help alleviate your concern, as security fixes are back-ported, not the newer release (except in rare circumstances where it's more work to backport a security fix, than provide/test a new version).  https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/

Comment: Soory, It was my mistake I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS system and trying to install openssh server latest version (8.6p1).

Comment: Please [edit] your question and put the extra details there, not in the comments. Thanks.